# Missing components in the CameraRoll API

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to access the gallery using the official CameraRoll API [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html). I am unable to render the component because the following modules are not provided in the official doc:

```
const CameraRollView = require('./CameraRollView');

const AssetScaledImageExampleView = require('./AssetScaledImageExample');
```

I tried to google for examples regarding `CameraRollView` and `AssetScaledImageExampleView` but found nothing. My question is where can I find the boilerplate code for these two modules? I am still learning React-Native so I am not sure how I am suppose to go about coding these two modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above the example code, next to the headline "Examples", you should see a link "Edit on GitHub" which leads to the source code for that example on GitHub. From there, you can navigate to the location of the file you desire.

For the particular files you desire, they are located at the following links:

[CameraRollView.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/CameraRollView.js)
[AssetScaledImageExample](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/AssetScaledImageExample.js)